# Let the Convention badge be tracked as "next badge"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, badge-progress

The [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) badge seems like a great candidate for a trackable badge: it requires doing a thing multiple times, there aren't any other requirements to get it, and it is (seems?) quite easy to determine how many times the thing has been done.

But Convention does not appear in the list of badges that can be tracked. I would like to be able to see a quick count of my well-received meta posts without going to my meta user activity page and poking around.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Meta is in a separate database, which makes it a lot harder to run checks for things because it requires connecting to a second database. Running checks like this in real time simply isn't a good use of resources or worth the performance issues it would cause, which is why the Meta and Chat badges were not included in the badge trackers.